# VS2010 Workflow Design Surface Inoperative

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, xamlx

I am using VS2010 and having an issue where upon opening my solution the Workflow.xamlx does not appear to render correctly.

The activities on the design surface only get drawn for the area that is initially visible when the xamlx loads.

To demonstrate the problem, I see the following. (I apologize for the blur)

[image: visible region]

The first problem is I can not use the vertical scroll bar to scroll the document. I can however, use the mouse wheel which reveals the second problem, that all of the activities, custom or standard appear as empty boxes.

[image]

I have tried the following

- Full Visual Studio reinstall.
- Video driver uninstall/reinstall (with reboots in between). Tried newer, older and some random video drivers as well.
- Removed a hotfix patch for Visual Studio installed in the last week, KB945140... just in case
- Disabled hardware acceleartion via "DisableHWAcceleration" and all various WPF registry settings.

I can zoom to 25%, collapse all of the activities, then expand them which because of the zoom level seems to force the activities to get redrawn. This is good as I can then see the icons, but I still can't scroll the document, not change the properties of activities at the root level of the workflow. The properties window reports "Property editing is not available" no matter where I click.

I have used a second instance of VS2010 to debug the first instance, no exceptions were thrown up into the debugger and looking at the debug output doesn't seem to reveal anything.

Comment: Seems to be a bug that many people are reporting to Microsoft, to me happened a few times, you can contribute and check [here][1]

  [1]: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586172/vs-2010-frequent-freezes-crashes

Comment: Doesn't crash on me as such, but thanks for the link!

Comment: If you convert your update to an answer, you will be able to select it and thereby close this question out.  It may seem odd to answer your own question, but it is the standard way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I have managed to resolve the issue by setting "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display" to 100% rather than the 125% I was using.